# Where can the Ladder card be placed in Saboteur 2?

Tags: saboteur-2

Most path cards in Saboteur can only be placed if they connect to the entry ladder  The Saboteur 2 rules say that a ladder path card is connected to the main entry ladder. Does this mean you can essentially place a ladder path card *anywhere* (presumably anywhere that connects to some other path) even if that path does not connect to the entry ladder?  (This would occur if some mean saboteur had played a rockfall on a key path card in the middle of stuff.)

The only thing I could find in the rules was that a ladder card cannot be placed next to the 3 final cards. What does that mean, exactly? Can I arbitrarily not place a ladder path card as the last card in a path to one of the end cards? Or are the rules just trying to say you can't use the ladder to teleport straight to the end when the groundwork (hah) has not yet been laid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was [answered by the Designer](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/667319/rules-on-ladder-placement), Frederic Moyersoen on BoardGameGeek:

> Any card you place in the gallery must match with an existing corridor. There is no exception for placing a card with a ladder.

[And here:](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/6433541#6433541)

> As the ladder is always connected to the start card, you can place this card when the connection is interrupted.

Taken together, the ladder card must be placed so that it connects to a path.  That path need not lead back to the original ladder card.